Are using website builder's, like Squarespace, OK to use when building a web-app that needs unique external components?
I'm a non-technical person starting a web-based project and would like some feedback as to whether or not building a website using a web-builder service like Squarespace will result in re-work once I introduce various other components that need to integrate to the website in order to create a bespoke application.
For context, I started off compiling requirements and mock-up screens (using figma) but as I've progressed I've become aware that I could apply the same level of effort I am now, but using a web-builder, and would effectively wind up with my screens AND the HTML/Javascript IP. At face-value it seems like a good win for efficiency.
That said, I know these builders don't support everything and have seen various comments floating around the internet indicating when building a bespoke web solution it's best to do so from scratch. But I don't know 100% as I also have learnt that it is possible to obtain the raw code for your website..
Has anyone had experience in anyway similar to this type of problem I'm looking at?
Please feel free to ask for clarification if my question is too high level and largely depends on a few key factors (e.g., 'What are you trying to do/build?' etc.).
Thanks!

"technical debt" isn't something you avoid by choosing between build-versus-buy,  indeed, it's generally not something you can avoid at all;   the longer that any system exists (Whether you built it yourself or not), the more time the world around you has chance to move on and evolve - peoples' expectations change, requirements change, as well as standards, laws, working practices, etc.    It's really more about how you manage the change.       Recommended reading  -- https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/02/27/stop-saying-technical-debt/

Thank you for the feedback regarding technical debt. I've revised the post to use the term 're-work.' The essence of the question is whether or not any savings I might achieve by using a web-builder instead of building mock-up screens will just be overturned once I ask a dev team to introduce other external components to integrate into the website. Looking for practical experiences from technical people.


Are using website builder's, like Squarespace, generally safe to use

"Safe"? Safe from what? That's a word with no meaning unless you elaborate what it is that you'd consider to be "not safe". Wasted hours? Limited design freedom? Licensing cost? Future-proofing? Bespokeness of the end product? Learning curve? Documentation reading effort? Documentation writing effort? Onboarding new people onto the project? ... (I can keep going)

I could apply the same level of effort I am now, but using a web-builder, and would effectively wind up with my screens AND the HTML/Javascript IP. At face-value it seems like a good win for efficiency.

This is a different way of saying

I don't need to figure out where I'm going right now, I just need to start driving and I'll figure it out on the road.

Which is trivializing one of the major complexities of development. You are assuming that when you are in the midst of technically building your components (whether this is building from scratch or configuring existing templates is an irrelevant distinction) that you will still be able to fully focus on freely making design decisions; and if you change your mind mid-way, that any change you'd make visually would be equally simple to execute in the technical component itself.
Neither of these statements are realistic estimates of the technical work required here. I'm not saying it's impossible, but doing doing two things at the same time has the equivalent complexity of doing three things separately. In your mind, you're thinking of how many straws you will indeed have to transport, but you're ignoring how strong the camel's back is.

That said, I know these builders don't support everything

I'll rephrase that from the POV of a technical person:

I will have to deal with inherent limitations in achieving my designs, and I'll either have to adjust/abandon my designs when this happens, or spend more time figuring out a clever way to achieve my goals anyway.

This is referring back to the "changing your mind mid-way" point I made earlier. Yeah, it's nigh impossible to get it right the first time and you will need to adjust mid-way, but be very careful about the amount of effort that this is going to entail if you're trying to design and build the application at the same time.

But I don't know 100% as I also have learnt that it is possible to obtain the raw code for your website.

Having the code and making sense of it are two very, very different things.
I cannot stress enough how different they are. A significant subset of developers have built entire careers on the skill of being able to take undocumented code and somehow revive it into a living codebase, and even the experts can barely keep such a project on life support (without refactoring to the point that it counts as rebuilding it from the ground up).
This is already true of a bespoke application that matches your specific requirements, let alone you thinking of doing this with a templated web builder.
Templated web builders add significant layers of abstractions specifically because they have to build components that work for everyone's use case, not just yours. When done well, you don't notice it in the frontend, but the code is a very different topic.
I'm hammering this point home because I want to contrast it to something else you said:

At face-value it seems like a good win for efficiency.

Try justifying your "I get the raw code, I take it from there" approach with efficiency. It's multiple orders of magnitude more inefficient than needing to do a UI design and technical build in two steps; and the fact that you don't see this is worrying for the technical direction this project is going in.
Based on your proposed solutions, I genuinely believe that you do not have the experience of building anything technical behind you; while at the same time trying to improve on and find shortcuts in the technical work before you.

Please feel free to ask for clarification if my question is too high level

Your question is too high level, but not in the way you intended (i.e. possibly needing to clarify further details in your posted question). You're making high level decisions about lower level implementations without any experience with actually executing the lower level.
I can tell that you did take some stabs at technical research, which is good; but you're running with what is a very crude and rudimentary understanding, running with it as if it's an expert opinion that has exhaustively considered all the ins and outs of the options you're considering, and then trying to apply it in a different from the tried and true development path (e.g. you know about making UI mockups before developing, but then you subvert it into a clever effort-saving trick to not do it).

Long term, even putting this specific question aside, I am concerned about the road you are leading this project down.
If this project is a business venture, I very strongly suggest you onboard a technical person to sanity check the work that you're trying to perform (and just have them do the work for you instead). Don't try to be your own dentist. It's not going to end well.
For this specific question, it's irrelevant to the larger issue. Build vs buy has tradeoffs that mostly depend on the freedom of your designs and the complexity of the building stage; but they are eclipsed by the kinds of problems you're thinking of (unwittingly) introducing to the project, based on things you've mentioned in this question (let alone any other ideas you might be having which didn't seem on-topic to bring up for this question).
Really reconsider if you're making informed decisions here, because I'm not convinced you are.

Thanks for the detailed response and breakdown. Particularly the bit about having code vs. understanding it... I think that's a great point.

@DylanSteele: Again, needs much more consideration than your question contains. This isn't an either/or, you need both. Someone cannot derive the complexities of working with a builder template purely by observing an existing site via its URL. At best, you're going to get an estimate based on an assumption of how something needs to be built. Estimates based on assumptions can only be as correct as the assumptions themselves are. At the same time, someone cannot estimate the work if you don't tell them what behavior you need and what it needs to look like.

@DylanSteele: Without trying to offend, you need to think this through more. You're also not really managing the project effectively on a higher level. The question shouldn't be about selecting which information to share, or to be so economical with your time and effort that you're trying to minimize the amount of information shared. If you cut costs in your development before you've even involved the first technical person, you will receive a shoddy end product, and that already being optimistic about even delivering the product at all.

Not offended, thanks again. It's an open-ended question so these responses are exactly what I need. Hopeful to get more perspectives over the next few days as well. :)


I'm a non-technical person starting a web-based project

Presumably, if you are not technical, an off the shelf solution is the only one available to you.
These off the shelf solutions can do a lot, but if you have complicated logic or multiple components to put in your app, it's still complicated and may be beyond a non-technical person.
The reason not to build your app in one of these frameworks is that you become locked into the framework and its limitations and it makes it hard to develop something that's different from your competitors.
It will depend on the specifics of your "unique external components". If there is an easy way to spin it up with squarespace or wordpress or something, then you should totally do that and worry about rewriting it later.
If the idea needs something the framework just can't do, or requires some funky workaround to make it sort of work, then whatever you end up making is going to lack the polish of a professional solution. It will make it hard to sell, it's not the 90's anymore, people expect nice UX.

Thanks, Ewan. Very practical perspective.
